# Java - How to add JComboBox Header

Tags: java, checkbox

[image]I'm trying to make a JComboBox with a header that cannot be selected just displayed..any help? How can i make the day element just a header?

```
    m2.addItem("Day:");
    m2.addItem("1");
    m2.addItem("2");
    m2.addItem("3");
    m2.addItem("4");
    m2.addItem("5");
    m2.addItem("6");
    m2.addItem("7");
    m2.addItem("8");
    m2.addItem("9");
    m2.addItem("10");
    m2.addItem("11");
    m2.addItem("12");
    m2.addItem("13");
    m2.addItem("14");
    m2.addItem("15");
    m2.addItem("16");
    m2.addItem("17");
    m2.addItem("18");
    m2.addItem("19");
    m2.addItem("20");
    m2.addItem("21");
    m2.addItem("22");
    m2.addItem("23");
    m2.addItem("24");
    m2.addItem("25");
    m2.addItem("26");
    m2.addItem("27");
    m2.addItem("28");
    m2.addItem("29");
    m2.addItem("30");
    m2.addItemListener(null);
    m2.setBounds(900, 477, 50, 20);
```

Comment: you mean `JCheckBox` or `JComboBox` ?

Comment: ok, check my answer now

Comment: Since this question popped up, use a JLabel to hold the JComboBox heading.  The JLabel can be placed above or to the left of the JComboBox.

Answer (score 1):

Ok you way is correct to add a head, if you want to use it later then you can avoid the first index :

```
m2.addItem("Day:");
m2.addItem("1");
m2.addItem("2");

if(m2.getSelectedIndex() != 0){
   //you can use your choise :
   String x = String.valueOf(m2.getSelectedItem());
}else{
   //you can print an error or avoid your action 
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to make a default selected then use this :

```
m2.addItem("Day:");
for(int i = 1; i <= 30; i++){
  m2.addItem(i+"");
}
//set the 1st element selected by default
m2.setSelectedIndex(1);
```

If you dont want to use index then you can use also `m2.setSelectedItem` to select the item

```
m2.setSelectedItem("5");
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: do i have to add an item/action listener before doing the if loops

Comment: what IDE you are using @RediRamaj

Comment: @RediRamaj learn this http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing/JComboBoxaddActionListenerActionListenerlis.htm this can help you

Comment: sorry but i don't know :3

Comment: what you don't know @RediRamaj

Comment: the IDE im using...also i used the code that you wrote and still the day gets selected...its not a header yet :/

Comment: it is selected because it is the first value of your `JComboBox` so what you want to select it in first?

Comment: @RediRamaj it is selected because it is the first value of your `JComboBox` so what value you want to set selected in first?

Comment: i want to avoid the day* element selection but i still want it to be the header.....i want to start the selection from 1-30

Comment: @RediRamaj check my answer now

Comment: can you put an image about what you want @RediRamaj ?

Comment: look now,i uploaded an image

Comment: @RediRamaj if you don't want to display it the don't put it in your JComboBox delete this `m2.addItem("Day:");` from your code

Comment: @RediRamaj can we talk in chat room?

Comment: How ? Uv got an email or smth...cuz it doesnt let me in the chatroom

Comment: mmm, i tried to understand you and to gives an answer but

Comment: its ok @RediRamaj hope you get a solution soon

Answer (score 0):

**Please note that I am answering a question that was asked over 3½ years ago.**

I believe that the following code achieves what you are trying to do. Explanations after the code.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class MenuTest implements Runnable {
    private JFrame  frame;
    private JTextField  textField;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        showGui();
    }

    private JPanel createMenuPanel() {
        JPanel menuPanel = new JPanel();
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu menu = new JMenu("Day      \u25BC");
        JList<Object> list = new JList<Object>(new Object[]{" 01",
                                                            " 02",
                                                            " 03",
                                                            " 04",
                                                            " 05",
                                                            " 06",
                                                            " 07",
                                                            " 08",
                                                            " 09",
                                                            " 10",
                                                            "11",
                                                            "12",
                                                            "13",
                                                            "14",
                                                            "15",
                                                            "16",
                                                            "17",
                                                            "18",
                                                            "19",
                                                            "20",
                                                            "21",
                                                            "22",
                                                            "23",
                                                            "24",
                                                            "25",
                                                            "26",
                                                            "27",
                                                            "28",
                                                            "29",
                                                            "30"});
        list.setPrototypeCellValue("9999");
        list.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me) {
                Point p = me.getPoint();
                list.setSelectedIndex(list.locationToIndex(p));
            }
        });
        list.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
                textField.setText(list.getSelectedValue().toString());
                menu.getPopupMenu().setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);
        menu.add(scrollPane);
        menuBar.add(menu);
        menuPanel.add(menuBar);
        return menuPanel;
    }

    private JPanel createTextFieldPanel() {
        JPanel textFieldPanel = new JPanel();
        textFieldPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 30, 10, 30));
        textField = new JTextField(8);
        textFieldPanel.add(new JLabel("Selected"));
        textFieldPanel.add(textField);
        return textFieldPanel;
    }

    private void showGui() {
        frame = new JFrame("Menu");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createMenuPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createTextFieldPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new MenuTest());
    }
}
```

I use a `JMenu` since when you click on a `JMenu`, it [usually] displays a list of menu items and allows you to select one. However you can add any [Component](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html) to it, so I added a `JScrollPane` that contains a `JList`.

In order to simulate the behavior of a `JComboBox` where moving the mouse over the list items highlights the item under the mouse pointer, I added a `MouseMotionListener` to the `JList`.

And in order to simulate the behavior of a `JComboBox` whereby selecting an item in the list by clicking on it with the mouse, closes the popup list, I added a `MouseListener` to the `JList`. Note that the `MouseListener` also displays the `JList` selected item in the `JTextField`.